# how to check in code that extension was changed or not?

Tags: c#, file, streamreader

**how to check in code that extension was changed or not?**

when I have **abc.png** file in "d:\" location I changed that extension **abc.txt**

my program is read txt file but in this case **abc.png** is image file change extention to **abc.txt** when i read **abc.txt** that time error message display "this file is extention is .png you changed to .txt so can't read"

Comment: You can't. That information has gone. You may be able to spot that it isn't a valid text file in the encoding you're using, or you could detect that the content looks suspiciously like a PNG file, but I wouldn't expect the file system to have a complete history of the previous names of the file.

Comment: You Cannot just change the extension from ".png" to ".txt". The file cannot be read.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to address, the scenario you describe does not seem likely to happen often enough to worry about.

Comment: @Adds -- That's the OP's point.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about something that can detect what a file's type is, by looking at the pattern of bits or even bytes in the file, which, if it were possible (maybe there's a library out there that can do that), it wouldn't be fool proof.  I could create my own file type and this library wouldn't know about it.  Even if it were a well-known file type, it doesn't necessarily have a pattern that makes it discernible.